# Set default value to a ForeignKey Field based on data-table row clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

I have 2 data-table in my app, onClick on any of the `project-content-datatable` row will display its child content on a second table (Content Table), Now in my second table I have a button to pop-up a form in modal to create new content in it, In that form how I can set the default value of the `parent_project_content = models.ForeignKey(ProjectContent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)` based on which row `project-content-datatable` user click at.

Any help is much appreciated, Thank you

Here is my code
HTML

```
<table id="project-content-datatable" class="display table table-hover table-responsive" style="width: 100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="small text-muted text-uppercase"><strong>Name</strong></th>
        <th class="small text-muted text-uppercase"><strong>Description</strong></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for content in content_list %}
        {% if content.search_type.name == searchtype.name %}
            <tr class="text-primary">
                <td class="text-left" style="cursor: pointer"
                    onclick='load_workorder({{ content.id }});'>
                    {{ content.id }}
                </td>
                <td class="text-left" style="cursor: pointer" onclick='load_workorder({{ content.id }});'>
                    {{ content.name }} </td>
            </tr>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor content_list %}
    </tbody>
</table>
<!-- END Hover Table -->


<!-- WORKORDER START-->
    <h3 class="panel-title text-white">WorkOrders</h3>
 <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
    <button
        data-toggle="modal" data-target="#create_new_workorder"
        type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-outline"><span
        class="hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs">Create Workorder</span> <i
        class="fa fa-fw fa-plus"></i>
    </button>
</div>
<!--Create Workorder Form Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="create_new_workorder" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
     aria-labelledby="TitleLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&#xD7;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Create New Workorder</h4>
            </div>
            <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
                <div class="modal-body">
                    {{ workorder_form.as_p }}
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"
                           value="Create Workorder"/>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

model.py

```
class WorkOrder(models.Model):
     parent_project_content = models.ForeignKey(ProjectContent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField(default='workorder of project content', blank=True)
    assign_to = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='assign_to', null=True, blank=True)
```

form.py

```
class CreateWorkorderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = WorkOrder
        fields = ['parent_project_content','description', 'assign_to',]
```

view.py

```
def content_view(request, project_id):
    """
    :param request: 
    :param project_id: 
    :return: 
    """
    selected_project = get_object_or_404(Project, id=project_id)
    search_type_list = selected_project.search_type.all()
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, id=project_id)
    form = CreateProjectContentForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    workorder_form = CreateWorkorderForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)

    if workorder_form.is_valid():
        instance = workorder_form.save(commit=False)
        instance.parent_project_content = WorkOrder.objects.get(parent_project_content=24)
        instance.save()

    if form.is_valid():
        inst = form.save(commit=False)
        inst.project = project
        inst.save()

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'workorder_form': workorder_form,
        "search_type_list": search_type_list,
        "selected_project": selected_project,
        "content_list": ProjectContent.objects.all().filter(project=selected_project.id),
        "content_id": WorkOrder.objects.all,
    }
    return render(request, 'dashboard/projects/content.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

create a separate view for handling workorder form,place an 'href' on the button that pops up the work order form, this is going to lead you to the view that handles workorder submission something like:

```
href="{% url 'workorder_handle' pk=content.pk %}"
```

your urls.py would be like:`

```
url(r'/workorder_form/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', workorder_view, name='workorder_handle'),
```

I'm imagining things here, replace what needs to be replaced

Comment: Hi @Mani, thanks for your reply, can you give me a full example of the view, as I am trying now and its not working.

Comment: did you retrieve the pk in the view? you can retrieve it from kwargs like: pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'), and then ProjectContent.objects.get(pk=pk). I am assuming you want this pk to assign to the new workorder, am I right?

Comment: yes that the issue right now, i dont know how to get the pk, I'm sorry, I'm very new to programming